# Cannot 'find' on mutableListOf

Tags: kotlin

The `mytable` object contains the `columns` variable (the `CollectionColumns` class) and the `list` variable is declared in this class, which contains objects of the `Column` class.

I try to search in this list by the variable `name` and don't find it (returns null).

```
val myTable = Table()
myTable.columns.add("Date")
myTable.columns.add("Name")
myTable.columns.add("Summ")

val find = myTable.columns.find("Summ")
println(find)
```

result: `null`

Does anyone know why ?

```
class Table() {

            var columns: CollectionColumns
            var rows: CollectionRows

            init {
                columns =  CollectionColumns()
                rows    =  CollectionRows()
            }

            inner class CollectionColumns() {

                var list = mutableListOf<Column>()

                fun add(_name: String): Table.Column{

                    val newColumn = Column(_name)
                    columns.list.add(newColumn)

                    for (row in rows.list) {
                        row.data.put(newColumn.name, null)
                    }

                    return newColumn
                }

                fun find(_name: String): Column?{

                    val findColumn = columns.list.find  { it.name == _name }
                    return findColumn
                }
            }

            class Column(_name: String) {
               val name = _name
            }

            inner class CollectionRows() {

                var list = mutableListOf<Row>()

                fun add() : Table.Row {
                    val newRow = Row()

                    for (column in columns.list) {
                        newRow.data.put(column.name, null)
                    }

                    rows.list.add(newRow)
                    return newRow
                }
           }

            class Row() {

                var data = mutableMapOf<String, Any?>()
                }
           }
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, i recreate project and it works (before i using "Kotlin Script").